# Mysql, error on inserting data

Tags: php, mysql

The variables are not null, i verify on the top of query, but i get a error. 
The script works but now , i get this error, please help, thanks.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO proads_users (email,username,facebook_user,facebook_uid,reg_date,approved,active,account_id,account_last_payment,account_next_payment,payment_mode,balance,max_credit,salt,country,shop_account_id,shop_active,state,payment_status,shop_name,mail_activated,setting_quantity_number,name,address,city) 
VALUES('$email','$uzernaim','1','$user','$timeme','1','1','2','$timeme','0','2','0.00','0.00','a3bc4re','2002','4','1','234','confirmed','$uzernaim','1','1','$name','Default','Default'") or die("Error: ".mysql_error());
```

I get this error : 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''

Comment: Whenever you have to write this kind of long query, try to use "INSERT INTO TABLE SET FIELD=VALUE", so that you can find where the query generates any error. My suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace

```
,'Default'")
```

with

```
,'Default')")
```

you forgot closing bracket

Comment: I didn't even spot this after looking at `VALUES('$email', ...` :)

Answer (score 1):

Closing Bracket ")" is missing in the query **'Default')"**

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO proads_users (email,username,facebook_user,facebook_uid,reg_date,approved,active,account_id,account_last_payment,account_next_payment,payment_mode,balance,max_credit,salt,country,shop_account_id,shop_active,state,payment_status,shop_name,mail_activated,setting_quantity_number,name,address,city) 
VALUES('$email','$uzernaim','1','$user','$timeme','1','1','2','$timeme','0','2','0.00','0.00','a3bc4re','2002','4','1','234','confirmed','$uzernaim','1','1','$name','Default','Default')") or die("Error: ".mysql_error());
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections; consider rewriting your queries with [prepared statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement).
Probably, the error is caused by `$email`, `$name` or some other variable containing quotes.

Comment: How do you know this query is vulnerable?

Comment: Because $email could be e.g. `', '', '', ..., ''); drop table proads_users; --`. In order to prevent such queries one would need to sanitize all input fields, which is not reliable (as someone may forget to sanitize some of the fields, especially if they're taken from different sources); from the other hand, it is possible to accidentally escape the quotes two times, malforming the original data supplied by user. I believe that with your reputation on SO you know this better than me!

Comment: I don't understand "someone may forget" reason. Someone may forget to prepare as well. I don't understand "escape twice" reason - someone may escape prepared data as well. Anyway, the question was "How do you know this very query is vulnerable?"

Comment: With the prepared statements, all the processing is done in a single place. For example, with the query supplied in the question, the new developer never will know if some variable is escaped or not unless they'll check the entire call stack. With the prepared statements it is clear that no malicious data will be processed. With the prepared statements, there are simple rules: no escaping, no data in query strings. With the manual escaping, what are the rules? Where the escaping should occur? How do we check that e.g. our "where" covered all the data sources.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7991/discussion-between-penartur-and-col-shrapnel)